# Down sampling problem: difference between resample and asfreq

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing with a time series dataframe defined as `df` using `pandas`. 
I've already changed the row index as datetime index using `set_index`.
I want to downsample a dataframe at 5 second interval using `resample` or `asfreq`. 
Let say downsample to 1 hour.

```
df_inst = df.asfreq('1H')    
df_inst2 = df.resample('1H')
```

When I execute above written code, `asfreq` gave me the right data frame downsampled to 1 h interval, which is exactly I expected to see.

However, `resample` didn't generate any dataframe variable, moreover, there is no error message.

When inspect it using `print`, I have the following message.

```
print(df_inst2)
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<Hour>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]
```

What am I missing? 
More specifically, how can I get the results using `resample` as I used `asfreq`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) returns a `Resampler object` while [`DataFrame.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) returns the data converted.

If you want to use `resample` correct, use it with a specific method, for instance: `df.resample('1H').asfreq()`.

Example from the docs:

```
>> index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
>> series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
>> series.resample('30S').asfreq().head(5)

2000-01-01 00:00:00   0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:30   NaN
2000-01-01 00:01:00   1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:30   NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:00   2.0
Freq: 30S, dtype: float64
```